# Check for img src keyword in a string

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I have a blog system where user inputs the image url in the post content like

```
hey how are you <img src="example.com/image.png">
```

if the user has written like this

```
hello how are you <img src="example.com/image.png">
```

Then I want to find this `img` `src` line and use it as featured image

here is what I have tried:

```
$haystack = 'how are you <img src="hey.png">';

$needle = '<img src="';

if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {

    echo "$needle";

}
else { echo "no"; }
```

When I echo I only get:

```
 <img src="
```

I want to get whole

```
<img src="hey.png">
```

from that string how can I do this.

Comment: You should use regex instead.

Comment: Regex, `preg_match('/(<img .*?>/', $string, $img_tag);`.

Comment: @chris85 
 
i'm getting one more problem if user is entering two time <img src="example.png"> then preg_match is showing both img tag and all the text beetween these two images i only want one image tag

Comment: Posted an answer below that I think should resolve your issue.

Comment: @chris85 still it's showing two images in array

Comment: @chris85 could you just tell me how could i select the first image tag from that array and insert in database as featured image

Comment: See updated answer, that is using `preg_match`. If that works for you please accept the answer; or post comments on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$string = 'hey how are you <img src="example.com/image.png"> test test <img src="example.com/image2.png">';
preg_match_all('/(<img .*?>)/', $string, $img_tag);
print_r($img_tag[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="example.com/image.png">
    [1] => <img src="example.com/image2.png">
)
```

You should consider using a parser for this though. They have a lot more functionality already built in than a regex, and will error cleaner.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/iY1wX0/1

or if you really only over want the first `img` just use `preg_match`.

```
<?php
$string = 'hey how are you <img src="example.com/image.png"> test test <img src="example.com/image2.png">';
preg_match('/(<img .*?>)/', $string, $img_tag);
echo $img_tag[1];
```

Output:

```
<img src="example.com/image.png">
```

Comment: I can't upvote your answer as i need more 4 points to start upvoting answer

Comment: @abhishekverma Accept, not upvote. You can accept an answer on every question you ever ask. Click the link in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` returns the index of where the needle starts in the haystack. Look at combining the returned value with `substr` and `haystack` to get the substring you want.

Answer (score 0):

As the image src is an unknown, use regex, something like this (off the top of my head, so it may be incorrect syntax):

```
$string = "hey how are you <img src=\"example.com/image.png\">"; 
$return = preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', '$string', $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expression** to match that string. It have been a long time since I left php... So it's something like below:

```
<?php
  $pattern = '/<img\ssrc\=".*?">/';
  $haystack = 'how are you <img src="hey.png">';

  preg_match($pattern, $haystack, $matches);

  print_r($matches);
?>
```

And the result will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="hey.png">
)
```

Check out [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

This is most probably way easier with using a [Regular Expression (RegEx)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Here is an simple example:

```
$string = 'hey how are you <img src="example.com/image.png"> blah blah';
preg_match('/<img src=".*">/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which would give you an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="example.com/image.png">
)
```